# How does the implicit conversion for int2double come in scope

Tags: scala, implicit-conversion, implicit

The following conversion works because of **int2double** implicit conversion

```
scala> val d: Double = 2
d: Double = 2.0
```

prior to 2.10, this implicit conversion was part of **Predef** object and was thus always in scope. However since 2.10, it has been moved to Int companion object. How does the implicit conversion still work without any import?

Answer (score 2):

For implicits, besides the local scope (including imported ones), there is the implicit scope

[Where does Scala look for implicits?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5598085/where-does-scala-look-for-implicits)

https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/07-implicits.html

> The actual arguments that are eligible to be passed to an implicit parameter of type  fall into two categories. First, eligible are all identifiers  that can be accessed at the point of the method call without a prefix and that denote an implicit definition or an implicit parameter. An eligible identifier may thus be a local name, or a member of an enclosing template, or it may be have been made accessible without a prefix through an import clause. If there are no eligible identifiers under this rule, then, second, eligible are also all implicit members of some object that belongs to the implicit scope of the implicit parameter's type, .
>
> The implicit scope of a type 
> consists of all companion modules of classes that are associated with the implicit parameter's type. Here, we say a class  is associated with a type  if it is a base class of some part of .
>
> The parts of a type  are:
>
> - ...
> - if  is a parameterized type `[1,…,]`, the union of the parts of  and `1`,…,;
> - ...

Implicit conversion `Int => Double` is `Function1[Int, Double]`, so companion objects of `Function1`, `Int`, `Double` will be investigated.